# Was anyone able to connect JumpCloud to Rundeck via LDAP?

Tags: ldap, rundeck

I've been trying to connect JC to Rundeck via LDAP for two days without any luck. Username and password for the bind user are 100% correct.

Error:

```
ERROR jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule - Naming error
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
```

Has anyone been able to configure this successfully?

my jaas-ldap.conf file looks like this:

```
    com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule sufficient
      debug="true"
      contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
      providerUrl="ldaps://ldap.jumpcloud.com"
      bindDN="uid=<username>,ou=Users,o=<xxxxxx>,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com"
      bindPassword="<password>"
      authenticationMethod="simple"
      forceBindingLogin="false"
      userBaseDn="ou=Users,o=<xxxxxx>,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com"
      userRdnAttribute="uid"
      userIdAttribute="uid"
      userPasswordAttribute="userPassword"
      userObjectClass="posixAccount"
      roleBaseDn="ou=Users,o=<xxxxxxx>,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com"
      roleNameAttribute="cn"
      roleUsernameMemberAttribute="memberUid"
      roleMemberAttribute="memberUid"
      roleObjectClass="posixGroup"
      cacheDurationMillis="300000"
      reportStatistics="true"
      supplementalRoles="user"
      timeoutConnect="20000"
      nestedGroups="true";
```

Comment: Verify your LDAP tree to make sure that your matches with userBaseDn and userPasswordAttribute. 2) your users also need a role, check the role entries, my current configuration: https://pastebin.com/kj5vYce9. Also, you can check a good example here: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#login-module-configuration

Comment: Thank you. Added role attributes and verified userBaseDn and userPassword. Still getting the same "invalid credential" error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rundeck {
com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCombinedLdapLoginModule sufficient
    debug="true"
    contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
    providerUrl="ldap://ldap.jumpcloud.com:389"
    bindDn="uid=xxxxxxxxx,ou=Users,o=xxxxxxxxxxxx,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com"
    bindPassword="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    authenticationMethod="simple"
    forceBindingLogin="true"
    forceBindingLoginUseRootContextForRoles="true"
    userBaseDn="ou=Users,o=xxxxxxxxxxxx,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com"
    userRdnAttribute="cn"
    userIdAttribute="uid"
    userPasswordAttribute="userPassword"
    userObjectClass="person"
    roleBaseDn="ou=Users,o=XXXXXXXXXXX,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com"
    roleNameAttribute="cn"
    roleMemberAttribute="uniqueMember"
    roleObjectClass="(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=*))"
    rolePrefix=""
    cacheDurationMillis="600000"
    reportStatistics="true"

;

org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
    debug="true"
    file="/home/rundeck/server/config/realm.properties";
```

};

Works for me :D

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.